# Is there a way to use similar method to OpenCv's MinMaxLoc to get a list of n max values instead of only one max value?

Tags: c#, opencv

`MinMaxLoc` returns `min` and `max` values of a given `input array`, however I would like to gent the `n` `max` values of that array?

Is the only way to do a loop, if so how to to do it using `OpenCvSharp`?

My image is something like:

[image]

Comment: Is the array one dimensional or multi-dimensional? Why do you want to do it using `OpenCvSharp`?

Comment: My particular input is a 2.dimensional array of a gray Image

Comment: After some googling I can't seem to find a general solution using OpenCvSharp :( I think you'll have to roll your own solution. My c# is rusty so I don't know how useful my manual c# solution would be. I can show how I might do it in python if you'd like.

Comment: Yeah, python could be very useful

Comment: Added an answer, hopefully I interpreted your question correctly and hopefully the answer is useful.

Comment: Is you array two dimensional as in jagged (T[][]) or rectangular (T[,])?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it in python (my c# is rusty and I couldn't find anything on google about how to find the n largest elements in `OpenCvSharp`).

```
data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

# first, collapse the 2 dimensional input into 1 dimension
collapsed_data = []
for row in data:
    collapsed_data.extend(row)

# now sort the collapsed input and get the 5 largest elements
sorted_data = sorted(collapsed, reverse=True)

k_largest = sorted_data[:k]
```

Note, there are more efficient ways to do this using min/max heaps but that's a lot of code to write and i'm not sure if you need the performance. If you do, those solutions are a google away.

Comment: K, this is useful, so I could use Linq or something, Will come back, Will check performance as I need it to be efficient

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a rectangular array you can get the n max values by:

```
var numValuesToGet = 2;
var inputArray = new int[,] {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};
var result = inputArray.Cast<int>().OrderByDescending(x=>x).Take(numValuesToGet);
```

Likewise, you could get the n min values by replacing `OrderByDescending` with `OrderBy`.